# Helper function in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a function which gives me a *guid*. However, I cannot figure how to actually implement it in Laravel 5, so I can use it in my controllers.

This is the function:

```
function getGuid() {
    return sprintf( '%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
        mt_rand( 0, 0x0fff ) | 0x4000,
        mt_rand( 0, 0x3fff ) | 0x8000,
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff )
    );  
}
```

How do I implement this, so I can access it from my controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feel free to put you function code anywhere in you project.
For example in `App/Support/helpers.php` file and after add this file to  `composer.json` `autoload.files` section. And this function will be  available in your project.

Autoload section of you composer file will look like this

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
      "app/Support/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

Laravel did same for this [helper functions](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers), look at 
vendor/laravel/framework/composer.json file and you will see this

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "src/Illuminate/Queue/IlluminateQueueClosure.php"
    ],
    "files": [
        "src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php",
        "src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Illuminate\\": "src/Illuminate/"
    }
},
```

Do not forget call **composer dump-autoload** after changes.

Answer (score 1):

create a `helpers.php` file in your app directory and include this line:

```
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ]
```

to your composer.json autoload:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```